# using dplyr with arguments from a Shiny controls

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

**EDIT: major rewrite has been done after reading comments**

With the `dplyr` package in R, I would like to:

- use `filter` to choose a particular row in my dataframe,
- use `select` to choose columns in my dataframe.

I have the row number for the row coming in from a numeric input box, called `input$num`.
I have the names for the columns coming in from a checkbox control, called `input$select`:

For example,
`print(input$num`) returns `10`, and
`print(input$select)`
returns `"Age"  "Weight"`.

So far so good.

*CASE 1:*
This works:

```
DF <- DF %>%
  filter(PIDN == input$num)
```

and I get row 10 and all the columns that exist in `DF`.

*CASE 2:*
This works, but ONLY when `input$select` holds `"Age"` or `"Weight"`, but not both:

```
DF <- DF %>%
  select_(input$select)
```

and I get all the rows and the single column `Age` or `Weight`.

*CASE 3:*
If `input$select` holds only `Age` or `Weight`, but not both, this does not work:

```
DF <- DF %>%
  filter(PIDN == input$num) %>%
  select_(input$select)
```

...and I get `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  column 'Age' has unsupported type`

I am totally baffled at this point. I am really interested in simply doing what *CASE 3* promises: select a particular row and some particular column(s).

Comment: Maybe try with `DF %>% select_(input$select)` ?

Comment: Does `input$select` return `Age` the (unevaluated) variable or `"Age"`, a character. I would think the easy way would be to use a character `"Age"` and then use `select_()`, the version that accepts characters.

Comment: sorry Gregor I forgot to include the `"` characters. I'll make an edit now. I had no idea there is a `select_` version.

Comment: Does it work as expected with `select_`?

Comment: I explored and tried, then ended up rewriting the question. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `filter_` instead

Comment: I give up. Nothing I do works. I'm going back to `DF <- DF[input$num, ]` followed by `DF <- subset(DF, select=input$select)`. I think my days of exploring `dplyr` are over for now!

Comment: It would be easier to find the answer if you provided a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If `input` is a list (as the variables have different lengths), then `dat %>% filter(PIDN == input$num) %>% select_(.dots = input$select)` works for me.